# understanding glm matrix format

Tags: c++, matrix, glm-math

I am encountering some issues using GLM, during the implementation of some matrix calculations. I got some code from my teacher/prof and I need to implement this part of the code using glm. He used some old self-written lib for it.

Here is some of the original code for a better understanding:

```
Mtx4x4 Mo = Mtx4x4(cam.right.x, cam.right.y, cam.right.z, cam.right*-cam.pos,
                   cam.up.x, cam.up.y, cam.up.z, cam.up*-cam.pos,
                   -cam.front.x, -cam.front.y, -cam.front.z, -cam.front*-cam.pos,
                   0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

For this it is obvious what to use: glm::mat4 should be the choice, but here is also my first problem: Which order should the parameters be for the glm::mat4? I got very confused reading about row major and column major order. In my C++ code I am creating the mat4 with the following code:

```
Mo = glm::mat4( orgCameraMat[0].x, orgCameraMat[0].y, orgCameraMat[0].z, (float)glm::dot(orgCameraMat[0],-orgCameraMat[3]), 
                        orgCameraMat[1].x, orgCameraMat[1].y, orgCameraMat[1].z, glm::dot(orgCameraMat[1],-orgCameraMat[3]), 
                        -orgCameraMat[2].x, -orgCameraMat[2].y, -orgCameraMat[2].z, glm::dot(-orgCameraMat[2],-orgCameraMat[3]), 
                        0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
```

Here I used some other names, but orgCameraMat is the modelview matrix of the camera as glm::mat4 (created using glm::lookAt)

My first question is: Are those matrices equal - produces my code the same matrix as the code above?

My 2nd question is: Later in the given code they use a Mtx3x4 Pt (which I assume is created from the Mtx4x4 P = perspective(fov, aspect, near, far)

Here is the calculation from the code:

```
Mtx4x4 P = perspectiveHorz(renderData.ofov, displayAspect, 0.1, 1000);
Mtx3x4 To = Mtx3x4(P) * Mo;
```

Mo is the 4x4 Matrix created above (see first question). 
 What is now a 3x4 matrix look like?

```
x x x x              x x x
x x x x        Or    x x x 
x x x x              x x x
                     x x x
```

Here is what I am doing for the 2nd part using GLM:

```
glm::mat4x3 pt = glm::mat4x3(

        P[0].x, P[0].y, P[0].z,
        P[1].x, P[1].y, P[1].z,
        P[2].x, P[2].y, P[2].z,
        P[3].x, P[3].y, P[3].z

                                );


    glm::mat4x3 To = pt * Mo;
```